# customize log filename of codeigniter log_message()

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

Is there anyway to customize the filename of log generated by `log_message()` in CodeIgniter 2.1.0? By default, it's filename was generated based on the current date.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`log_message()` function is common system function. Its using `Log::write_log()` method for logging error. Its not good hack the Core files. So you can extend Log library and overwrite `write_log()` function.

If you didnt extend your `Log` class yet. Create file `application/libraries/MY_Log.php`

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log  {

    function MY_Log ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function write_log() { //here overriding
        if ($this->_enabled === FALSE)
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        $level = strtoupper($level);

        if ( ! isset($this->_levels[$level]) OR
        ($this->_levels[$level] > $this->_threshold))
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        /* HERE YOUR LOG FILENAME YOU CAN CHANGE ITS NAME */
        $filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').EXT;
        $message  = '';

        if ( ! file_exists($filepath))
        {
        $message .= "<"."?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?".">\n\n";
        }

        if ( ! $fp = @fopen($filepath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE))
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        $message .= $level.' '.(($level == 'INFO') ? ' -' : '-').' ';
        $message .= date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        @chmod($filepath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Than `log_message()` function will work as your wish

Comment: Gets:Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in D:\projektai\roachrun\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Comment: Does this still work? I have literally copy pasted this, changing only the filepath, but the logs are still using default filename. Also tried adding <?php in the beggining, but this wont do.

Answer (score 2):

@safarov's answer is great, but a little out of date in terms of specific code, here's how to make your own:

- Create your MY_Log class as described by @safarov but don't overwrite the method yet.
- Find the file which contains the CI_Log class, in CI 3.1.10 it's called `Log.php` and if you're using composer you'll probably find it at `/vendor/codeigniter/framework/system/core/Log.php`
- In that file, find the `write_log` function and copy the whole thing into your new class.
- Edit that function to name the file how you wish.
- Don't forget to update this function when you update CI!

Answer (score 0):

With CI 2.1.3 made it work using this code. Created MY_Log.php in libraries folder. Not exact what needed the OP but everybody will understand how to modyfy :)

```
<?php 
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 4.3.2 or newer
 *
 * @package        CodeIgniter
 * @author        ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright    Copyright (c) 2006, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since        Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * MY_Logging Class
 *
 * This library assumes that you have a config item called
 * $config['show_in_log'] = array();
 * you can then create any error level you would like, using the following format
 * $config['show_in_log']= array('DEBUG','ERROR','INFO','SPECIAL','MY_ERROR_GROUP','ETC_GROUP'); 
 * Setting the array to empty will log all error messages. 
 * Deleting this config item entirely will default to the standard
 * error loggin threshold config item. 
 *
 * @package        CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage    Libraries
 * @category    Logging
 * @author        ExpressionEngine Dev Team. Mod by Chris Newton
 */
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $config =& get_config();

        $this->_log_path = ($config['log_path'] != '') ? $config['log_path'] : APPPATH.'logs/';

        if ( ! is_dir($this->_log_path) OR ! is_really_writable($this->_log_path))
        {
            $this->_enabled = FALSE;
        }

        if (is_numeric($config['log_threshold']))
        {
            $this->_threshold = $config['log_threshold'];
        }

        if ($config['log_date_format'] != '')
        {
            $this->_date_fmt = $config['log_date_format'];
        }
    }

    private function isCommandLineInterface()
    {
        return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli');
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Write Log File
     *
     * Generally this function will be called using the global log_message() function
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string    the error level
     * @param    string    the error message
     * @param    bool    whether the error is a native PHP error
     * @return    bool
     */        
   public function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)
    {


        if ($this->_enabled === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $level = strtoupper($level);

        if ( ! isset($this->_levels[$level]) OR ($this->_levels[$level] > $this->_threshold))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.php';
        $message  = '';

        if ( ! file_exists($filepath))
        {
            $message .= "<"."?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?".">\n\n";
        }

        if ( ! $fp = @fopen($filepath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ($this->isCommandLineInterface()) {
            $message .= 'CMD ';
        }

        $message .= $level.' '.(($level == 'INFO') ? ' -' : '-').' '.date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        @chmod($filepath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why there is an extension of php instead of log? '.log' not '.php'

Comment: No idea, probably CI developer for some reason decided so.

Comment: seems like a potential back door to me, I changed it back to log.